# SSIS derived column does not reflect variable's value

Tags: ssis

I have a pretty simple package. It reads a flat file, extracts date from a header record and subsequently uses derived column component to reformat data to the desired output format. One of the columns (`FileRunDate`, string, length 8) in the derived component is defined as a string and in the expression I'm assigning it to a variable I set earlier in the script component `- @[User::vRunTimeDate]`. When the process runs, the output file gets generated, however `FileRunDate` is blank. The default value of the variable is blank, however if I were to set it to some date, then the output file does reflect this value. It seems that the variable assignment in the script task does not work, but if I were to debug it, then I see how the value is being set. The variable has an attribute of ReadWrite.

Any feedback is greatly appriciated.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Your package has a variable `vRunTimeDate`. A script task processes the header row from your file and assigns a value to that variable. You then import the body of the file and what, you're trying to add the Variable into the data flow?

Comment: That is correct. After I extract a file run date from the input's file header and assign it to a variable, I reformat the incoming file by getting only elements I need. One of the derived columns, for each record to be written out to an output file should reflect the file run date from that variable.

Comment: Have you tried to set a break point and examine the value of @[User::vRunTimeDate] at run time? The problem is probably in the code setting that variable.

Comment: Here is the code I use to set this variable up - Variables.vRunTimeDate = strRunDate; where strRunDate is extracted from a header during execution of Input0_ProcessInputRow and the variable itself is set in PostExecute. I can verify that the value is being set during debugging. When I evaluate the variable's value in a subsequent script component for whatever reason it shows the default value I originally set the variable to.